# Even when supplying the correct username and password, it still returns false for if reader.HasRows(). Any ideas?

Tags: sql, vb.net, authentication

```
Protected Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim account As String = txtusername.Text
        Dim mypassword As String = txtpassword.Text
        Dim sqlCommand As New  _
            SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE User_ID ='@USE' AND Password='@PAS'", connection)
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USE", account)
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAS", mypassword)
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Dim values As New ArrayList()
        If reader.HasRows() Then
            Response.Redirect("https://google.com")
        Else
            Response.Redirect("https://yahoo.com")
        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

End Class

I am trying to build a simple login page and have verified that he SQL query and input is right, but for some reason it always returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried changing this

```
SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE User_ID ='@USE' AND Password='@PAS'", connection)
```

to this

```
SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE User_ID =@USE AND Password=@PAS", connection)
```

Comment: This didnt seem to work for the entire problem, although I do like the procedure better and changed mine to match.